# Forward declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

#### Background

I'm building a javascript based application that works differently on mobile and desktop devices. However, except for the DOM manipulation, most code is common between both platforms, so I have structured all files like:
* foo.core.js
* foo.mobile.js
* foo.web.js

And hoping to leverage object oriented techniques to write cleaner code.

#### Problem:

I have two JavaScript files, with classes

File 1:

```
function ClassA()
{}

ClassA.prototype.foo = function(){};

GreatGrandChildA.prototype = new GrandChildA(); // this is where the error is
function GreatGrandChildA ()
{}
```

File 2:

```
ChildA.prototype = new ClassA();
function ChildA () // ChildA inherits ClassA
{}

GrandChildA.prototype = new ChildA()
function GrandChildA () // GrandChildA inherits ClassA
{}
```

Normally, in a language like C++, I would forward declare `GrandChildA` right in File 1. I would like to know how to do it in Javascript

### Edit:

If I make a single file containing all four classes - in the same order in which they are loaded, the example works exactly as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2XKL/

Comment: Let me get this straight - you want to assign new instance of an class GrandChildA before it has been declared? Javascript natively doesn't support any way to do that.

Comment: When using plain javascript (without helper libraries) you must download js-file that contains _parent_ class definition before js-file that contains child class definition.
For your example: File2 must be downloaded before File1. Or you can merged both files into one.
If you need way to download childs classes before parent, you can use external library or implement your custom logic for downloading and creating classes.

Comment: @WTK: If I put everything in one file, it works great. Unfortunately, the way I've designed it prevents putting everything in one file. but now it looks like I'll have to re-structure the entire application.

Comment: @Andrew - The problem is that the scripts are executing one after the other. So no matter which code executes first, it'll fail. Funnily enough putting both the scripts in the same file solves the issue. But that's something I Cannot do

Comment: @skyronic yes you may need to re-structure your code organization. And read about hoisting in Javascript runtime to understand why your File 2 actually works

Comment: @skyronic: I know about this all. But it's posible to implement logic, that can make posible to download files in any order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple logic for unordered js file loading:

File1:

```
// ClassB: inherite from ClassA
(function ClassB_Builder() {
  if(window.ClassB)return; // ClassB is already defined;
  if(!window.ClassA) { // ClassA is already not defined;
     setTimeout(ClassB_Builder,0); // shedule class building
     return;
  }
  ClassB=function() {
  }
  ClassB.prototype=new ClassA;
  ClassB.prototype.constructor=ClassB; // can be important for inheritance!!!
})();
```

File2:

```
// ClassA: base class
(function ClassA_Builder() {
  ClassA=function() {
  }
})();

// ClassC: inherite from ClassB
(function ClassC_Builder() {
  if(window.ClassC)return; // ClassC is already defined;
  if(!window.ClassB) { // ClassB is already not defined;
     setTimeout(ClassC_Builder,0); // shedule class building
     return;
  }
  ClassC=function() {
  }
  ClassC.prototype=new ClassB;
  ClassC.prototype.constructor=ClassC; // can be important for inheritance!!!
})();
```

Comment: Wow, that's one crazy hack. I haven't ever seen anyone try to tackle it that way. Funnily enough, it seems to work quite well for development, though I'll probably have a script to remove this section during production.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that on your HTML page, you import File 1 and then File 2.

In **File 1**, you should see exception because "GrandChildA" is *undefined*. The function declaration is not done because File 2 has not loaded yet.

In **File 2**, you're being able to do:

```
ChildA.prototype = new ClassA();
function ChildA () // ChildA inherits ClassA
{}
```

because the Javacript runtime hoisted your *named function* "ClassA" **before** the code executes until `ChildA.prototype = new ClassA();`

Please read more about function hoisting and should you be doing it in such situation at http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 1):

The most sane way to accomplish what you want, is to make 2 separate versions of your source code. You're going to want to minify, obfuscate your code and merge all the source files anyway, so it would make sense to create a build script (python would be a great language for a simple build script) that you configure to merge mobile specific files into one (plus the files that both versions share) and non-mobile specific files into another file (and shared files also). In addition you could later add automatic obfuscating and gzipping. Then you can serve the appropriate source version to the appropriate client.

Comment: I am minifying all my scripts, but there's quite a bit of code. Unminified, it's hard to properly debug. Moreover, if there's an error on line 876, I wouldn't know where to look :(

Comment: @skyronic in my own dev setup, I have a no-minify flag that I can set when debugging so that it would be possible to track the exact line in chrome console and/or your favourite editor. Then the build script would only merge the files and not obfuscate/minify.

Comment: I wanted to avoid concatenating all of the files as much as possible. But now I guess there's no choice :/ I'm still seeing whether it's worth re-structuring to allow me to load all the files independently

Comment: Theres no real benefit to having multiple files anyway, even when debugging, in my opinion. Modern debuggers are friendly enough, so that I have no problems debugging a 4k line project. After applying proper obfuscation and gzipping it also comes down to less than 100kb.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, the requested functionality is not possible.
This is not only a technical problem but also an indication that
the application is not structured appropritately - the design should be improved.
Now, there is a kind of a circular dependency that shoul be avoided.

For comparison you mention that you would solve it in C++ by a forward declaration
of the superclass. But this is also not possible. In C++, 
in order to declare a subclass you need to **include** the file with the 
declaration of the superclass. And you cannot solve the problem when there are circular dependencies.

Comment: It's not a circular dependency. If I put everything in one file, it works fine. It's just unfortunate that JavaScript loads each file and executes them individually one by one. By concatenating the scripts, the objects are in scope. I just wanted to know if there's a way I could do this without concatenating the scripts.

Comment: This is a circular dependencies between the two files. File_1 needs file_2 to be loaded first. And file_2 needs file_1 to be loaded first.